# How to create pagination in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a problem with a section of my code. It's displaying a page link but it doesn't change to the page results. The URL changes as if it was on the second-page result but it's still displaying the same thing as the first.

I'm not too advanced in PHP and I was hoping somebody had a conclusion to this.
For additional information, this PHP code is being used in WordPress to list a group of audio files on the website.

```
function audioboard_welcome_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $list = '<ul class="audio_list">';
    $list .= '<div class="tracks_homepage">';

    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'limit' => 20, 'type' => 'audio'), $atts ) );

    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'post_type' => $type,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' =>'date',
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $date = '';

    while ($query->have_posts() ) {$query->the_post();

        if ( $date != get_the_date() ) {
            $date = get_the_date();
            $nicedate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date));
            $list .='<div class="added-on"><div class="date-added">Added on '.$nicedate.'</div><div class="aud-trating">Rating</div><div class="aud-tbpm">BPM</div></div>';
        }

        $list .= layout_for_large_list(get_the_ID());
    }

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $list .= '</div>';
    $list .= '<div class="mypagination"><nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation"><div class="nav-links">';
    $list .= paginate_links( array('base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),'format' => '?paged=%#%','current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),'total' => $query->max_num_pages) );
    wp_reset_query();
    $list .= '</div></nav></div>';
    $list .= '</ul>';

    // Pagination Start
    return $list;
}
```

Added an image for a better understanding of whats going on.
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8c1O.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the line near the top to be

`$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;`

---

What's happening is that the `get_query_var('paged')` is not for static pages which I assume yours is not since it is always returning the first-page content.

`get_query_var('page')` is used to get the current pagination number on a static front page.

You can read more about the function in the documentation here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#examples

Comment: Thank you for the response, this does actually allow the pages to be changed. But another problem that came about is it doesn't highlight the correct page number that is currently being viewed and it won't allow the user to revert to the previous page.